# JQuery Slide Issue

Tags: jquery, html, slider, slidedown, slideup

I'm having an issue with JQuery and it's slideUp and SlideDown functions. Basically, i have two navigation bars that slide out and in depending on which button the user clicks. However as a result of this the functions are knocking the content down a pixel or two (depending on which browser you are using although it's normally 1px down).

You can see a working example of the issue here: http://www.brianwritescode.com/index.php/blog/

Comment: I'm unclear about what you mean when you say _"knocking content down 1 pixel"_.

Comment: If you look closely, (i know its difficult to see at first but it could pose some problems in future), you will see that the content below the nav bar and even the nav bar itself pushes down 1 pixel.

Comment: I see it acting a little "jittery" but it definitely is not shifting 1 pixel at all (Safari 5.0.6).  I am using screen rulers to verify a zero pixel shift in content and menu-bar.

Comment: Whatever it is, you should be posting the relevant portion of the code and perhaps a jsFiddle so people can help you troubleshoot this.  Digging through your live code is going to be a pain.

Comment: apologies, i will remember this for next time i post up stuff. Thanks for your help. The absolute positioning solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem.

What you want to do is take these 2 nav elements out of the flow of the document so that they have no bearing on the content below. You could wrap these 2 navs inside a div and set that div to position absolute.

Comment: Hi FutureKode, there's another issue here with an additional animation. I've decided to fade the logo in and out depending on what colour of navigation is shown. The code for the nav is on the page within the iframe on the first entry http://www.brianwritescode.com

If you select the two nav options on the top right fast it shows two logos instead of one. Is there any way to sort that?